# Blender 2.80: Added mesh primitives too large everytime - how to change the defaults?

Tags: modeling

I set my scene to 'meters' and the unit scale to 1.0 since I need to know the size of the parts of the scene in meters.

Every time I add a cube or any other of the mesh primitives it starts WAY to big/large/huge and I need to scale it down.

Is there any way to instruct blender to not to throw such massive primitives at me? Where can I adjust this - if possible?